# Does the Windows Server 2019 ReFS implementation support compression?

Tags: windows-server-2019, refs

There seems to be a lot of chatter about Microsoft adding missing features to ReFS in Windows Server 2019. Is disk compression now available?  And if so, does it work in conjunction with data deduplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReFS does not support compression, but if you use deduplication on a ReFS volume, compression is used - at least according to this page https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/data-deduplication/whats-new

Screenshot:
[image: compression annotated on MS page]

Comment: Interesting, does this compress all files or are you saying that the deduplication is a form of compression? Is there a way to see statistics on a per file basis to confirm not only this, but how it's being applied and so forth (ie, size of file and size on disk)?

Comment: @ylluminate I cannot see any statistics on a per-file basis, but if you run the ddpeval.exe tool, it actually estimates your savings with deduplication - both before and after compression. I suspect that when dedup is used, all chunks that go into the dedup store are compressed. I am not sure if that has the effect of 'compressing' /all/ files, but I would suspect that all of your in-policy files will find themselves in the store with compression.

Comment: @ylluminate I added a link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/data-deduplication/whats-new

Comment: I appreciate your having noted that - I added an image in an edit for future reference. I'm curious, the latter annotated part says "optional compression" so I have to wonder: is there a way to turn it on since it is "optional?"

Comment: @ylluminate I cannot find any setting. My imagination says that whenever a file is optimised, the data is stored into chunks which are compressed before being stored. But I would love to see something more concrete get published into the docs. Maybe worth doing an experiment - empty volume, 1000gb file, see how much disk space is used?

Comment: From reading the screenshot you added, it says "variable-size chunk store with optional compression" but doesn't say if it's the administrator's option, or the deduplication system's option :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it appears that Microsoft has not yet added compression to ReFS in Windows Server 2019 (version 1709) as per [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview):

[image: table]